# can I obtain a value from a dexie DB without using the built-in promises

Tags: dexie

I'm writing an offline web page that needs to re-start from where it left off.
I've got the page(s) to read large JSON arrays, it builds various tables, it reads from the tables and now I need to "carry on where the user left off"

In javascript, I would normally get a value `var todaysDataObtained="";`
but now I need to get "todaysDataObtained" from the dexie database but everything seems to be based upon promises and the actual setting of the var immediately returns "" despite the console saying that the var should now be set to "not set"

```
var todaysDataObtained="";

db.todaysShift.toArray().then((records) => { 
   todaysDataObtained= records[0]["theDate"];
   console.error ("todaysDate is "+records[0]["theDate"]);
  }).catch (function (error) {
   console.error ("Transaction aborted due to error: " + error);
   console.error ("todaysDate is NOT set");
   todaysDataObtained="not set";
  });

alert(todaysDataObtained);
```

so how do I return a database entry into a javascript variable forcing the javascript to wait until the promise has completed and set the var correctly within the promises.

Once the var has been set, I can then use that to force the user to login to get todaysData or skip that step and move on knowing I have already got a populated database

Thanks Kevin,

Answer (score 0):

that's the way Promises work. It is really an asynchronous operation taking place lettings your browser possibly render some HTML in the meantime ore do other kinds of stuff. The `alert(todaysDataObtained);` happens before any of the callbacks.
You should really start your application logic from the callback and in addition don't use catch handlers for it:

```
db.todaysShift.toArray().then(records => { 
  if (record.length === 0) {
    // startup with empty db
  } else {
    // startup with data if that is any different 
    // from the first case
  }
})
.catch (error => {
    // error handling
});
```